# Fullcalendar boxes are not the same size

Tags: fullcalendar

I am having a problem with Fullcalendar. The calendar box sizes are not the same. I am using Google Calendar with it, and my website is running Bootstrap (which I suspect may be part of the problem). Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Here is my code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      defaultView: 'month',
      googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyAtQycskAlpsb3lvwq-ZQdYExUy4OkYVrw',
      events: {
        googleCalendarId: 'uu352qak2tcqa5fhf268g26a68@group.calendar.google.com'
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

[image: Picture of the Problem]

Comment: You might want to add the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Size of the box is expanded because you have events into it, You set event limit in the full calendar config object and you will get rid of it, sample code is as below,

```
 $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar: {
                height: 500,
                editable: false,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                views: {
                    month: {
                        eventLimit:3
                           }
                    }
                }
```

This should solve your problem..!!!

(Note: You should set limit as per your requirement which is optional
)